# Has somebody be able to adquire real time data of an CMS50D BT with python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have seen several codes that can deal with that but using the CMS50DPlus, however, the CMS50D BT does not use serial communication, it uses USB HID communication.

I tried to read the device's information but it says that the permission is denied, I also tried several ways to modify the permissions but withouth success.
I would appreciate the help of anybody here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.